# _gaq.push won't send data

Tags: javascript, analytics

somehow my `_gaq.push` function is not working. If I set `debug = true` I can see the logs, and I know it gets to the else (when I have `debug=false`) because I tried adding a log in it. Here's my code

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

var debug = false;

function send_data(text, url) {
    if (debug) {
        console.log("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site-change', " + text + ", " + url + "]);");
    } else {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site-change', text, url]);
    }
}

$('.navigation .child a').unbind('click').on('click', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var text = $(this).text();
    send_data(text, url);
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: how do you know it's not working? no request is seen in your network console when clicking? is google analytics properly loaded?

Comment: So you aren't seeing any outgoing image requests when calling `gaq._push`? What about trying an example like: `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday'])` in your browser console?

Comment: Exactly, no request is seen in the network tab and I can't find the __utm.gif thing. If I try an example the console logs '0'. This is strange

Comment: I recommend installing Google's GA Debug Chrome extension. It will log out everything GA is doing in the console and that might give you a little more to go on. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en.

Comment: @JonasGrumann. Hmm, it seems like GA is not loading properly. @ajm's suggestion is a good one. The debugger has been very helpful for me. You can try checking for the presence of `_.gat` and `_.gat._getTracker` as well

Comment: I installed the add on. I see the events in the console now, but still nothing in the network tab.